# Question about the definition of radians in the circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We know that every radian in a circle is equal to the size of the central angle facing the arc of the circle along the radius of the circle. Now the question has come to me that by changing the radius of the size of each radian should also change, but why does not this happen? I can not understand it well. Why is a radian in a circle with a radius of one unit equal to a radian in a circle with a radius of two?please help. Thankful
I'm sorry my English writing is weak

Comment: You change the radius and the circumference changes as well, but the proportion stays the same. $C=2\pi r$.

Comment: The central angle $\theta$ stays the same, because you have similar circles.  The arc-length changes with the radius $r$ since that is $r\theta$, but the ratio of the arc-length to the radius stays the same.  The area of the sector also changes since that is $\frac12 r^2 \theta$.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your explanation. If I'm not mistaken, what I've learned from your writing is that radians are actually the ratio of the arc size of a circle to the radius. Therefore, the ratio does not change with changing radius. So can we say that radians are without units? Because it is a ratio.

Comment: Radians are dimensionless for exactly the reason you just stated.

Comment: Radians are dimensionless though they are a derived SI unit.  This leads to Planck's constant being $h = 6.62607015\times 10^{-34}\ \text{J}{\cdot}\text{s}$ and the reduced Planck's constant being $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi} \approx  1.054 571 817\ldots\times 10^{-34}$ with units either of $\text{J}{\cdot}\text{s}$ or $\text{J}{\cdot}\text{s} {\cdot}\text{rad}^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you all very much, my dear professors, for your guidance.